# Adding pointers to hash table using hsearch_r

Tags: c, hashtable

I would like to add pointers to a hash table using hsearch_r. At the moment it does not work using the following code segment (without variable declarations and checks):

```
// Allocate hash table
htab = calloc( INITIAL_HASH_SIZE, sizeof(struct hsearch_data) );
hcreate_r( INITIAL_HASH_SIZE, htab );

// Add first pointer to hash table
he.key = (char *)&pointer_some_complex_struct1;
if ( hsearch_r( he, FIND, &hep, htab ) == 0) {
  he.data = pointer_some_complex_struct1->data;
  hsearch_r( he, ENTER, &hep, htab );
}

// Add second pointer to hash table
he.key = (char *)&pointer_some_complex_struct2;
if ( hsearch_r( he, FIND, &hep, htab ) ) {
  // CODE ENTERS HERE
}
```

The second call finds the object regardless it is not present. Any ideas what could be the problem with the above code segment?

Comment: As a complete aside, when allocating `htab`, I think you only need to allocate `1` such, not `INITIAL_HASH_SIZE`, whatever that may be

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the keys in hsearch/hsearch_r are NUL-terminated strings, not arbitrary data.

Comment: I just want to store the address of the pointer in the hash table. Any idea how can I do this then? Converting the address to integer and then to string?

Comment: The problem is that hsearch is not a generic hashtable, it's designed to only handle strings -- ie my advice would be to use anything else, or just write your own. That being said, you __could__ do it with eg sprintf's "%p", but then you'd have to malloc a new string for each pointer you're storing.